# Find the region defined by $x$, $y$ and $z$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$D = \{(x,y,z) \in R^3 \mid 1 \le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 9, z \le 0, |x| \le y, y \ge 0 \}$$

Find

$$\iiint \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$

My problem is defining the region $D$, I should be able to solve the triple integration fine.

Comment: First, observe that you can just omit $y \geq 0$ part because when $|x| \leq y$, $y$ cannot be negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've seen spherical coordinates, in which case it would be
$$
D = \{ (\rho, \phi, \theta) \mid 1 \le \rho \le 3,  \ \pi/2 \le \phi \le \pi,  \ \pi/4 \le \theta \le 3\pi/4\}
$$

Explanation: As you can tell, your region $D$ is a specific part of a sphere. By definition, $\rho^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$, so $1 \le \rho \le 3$ follows immediately.

Note that $\theta$ only describes the region in the $xy$-plane. So we ignore $z \le 0$ til we get to the $\phi$ variable. The inequalities in the $xy$-plane are $|x| \le y$, which is equivalent to $x \le y$ and $-x \le y$.

The plot of $x \le y$ is:

[image]

and the  plot of $-x \le y$ is:

[image]

The plot of $|x| \le y$ is the region that is shaded in both of them:

[image]

As you can see, $\theta$ goes from the line $y=x$ to the line $y=-x$, which corresponds to $\pi/4$ to $3\pi/4$.

Finally, $z \le 0$. This is going to be given in terms of $\phi$. Note $0 \le \phi \le \pi$ always. And $\phi$ is the angle from the positive $z$-axis downwards (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

So if $z \le 0$, we take $\pi/2 \le \phi \le \pi$.

Comment: I can find the interval for $1 \le \rho \le 3$ but not $\phi$ or $\theta$

Comment: Ok let me add a few things to the answer.

Comment: Let me know if the edit makes sense

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks very much!